# What is a local coordinate of a chart?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, definition, differential-forms, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a Riemann surface.
On p.106 of "Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces" Rick Miranda writes, when proving that it suffices to specify a holomorphic $1$-form on $X$ on any (not necessarily maximal) atlas:

> Let $\psi$ be a chart of $X$ not in a given atlas $A$; our task is to define the holomorphic $1$-form with respect to $\psi$ or, equivalently, **in terms of the local coordinate $w$ of $\psi$.**

What is a "local coordinate of a chart" (i.e. what is meant by "local coordinate $w$ of $\psi$" in this context)? Is $w$ another symbol for $\psi$? Is $w$ a function? If it is, I am confused about Miranda's subsequent notation "$f(T(w))T'(w)$". This notation makes it seem as if $w$ was a point in $\mathbb{C}$.

In the terminology I know, local coordinates are the coordinate functions of a chart (i.e. the composition of a chart with a projection). Here, we are considering charts from open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ to open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. Thus, local coordinates would simply be the same as charts.

Comment: A similar confusion is addressed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4621003/987103.

Comment: "Local coordinates for $\psi$" should mean "the linear coordinates on $\psi(U)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$". Presently, $n=2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{C}$, and you are considering both local coordinates $(x,y)$ simultaneously through the holomorphic coordinate $w=x+iy$. So it is not alternative notation for $\psi$.

Comment: @QuaereVerum Thank you! So you are saying that $w$ is the function $w\colon\psi(U)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}; (x,y)\mapsto x+iy$ where we identify $\psi(U)$ with a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (essentially again by $w$)? And the notation $f(T(w))$ actually denotes the following function composition $f\circ T \circ w\colon \psi(U)\subset \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying! (Although I am not sure what the domains of $T$ and $f$ are in your specific example - but you seem to have the right idea so you are probably correct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that Miranda's terminology may be a little confusing.

He defines a (complex) chart on $X$ to be a homeomorphism $\phi  : U \to V$, where $U \subset X$ is an open set in $X$, and $V \subset \mathbb C$ is an open subset in $\mathbb C$.

Then he writes

> We think of chart on $X$ as giving a local (complex) coordinate on its domain, namely $z = \phi(x)$ for $x \in U$.

My understanding is that the concept of *local coordinate* is not identical with the concept of *chart*:

A chart is a **map** $\phi : U \to V$, but a local coordinate is an **attribute of a point $x \in U$** (namely its image $\phi(x) \in V \subset \mathbb C$.

The connection is obvious: Each chart on $X$ gives a local coordinate to all points of its domain $U$, and we can reconstruct the chart if we know the local coordinates of all points in $U$.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense.

Comment: Is Miranda's terminology standard?

Comment: And if $w$ is the value of a chart at a point, how does the notation $dw$ make sense then? I thought $dw$ denotes the differential (or more generally exterior derivative) of a form? And forms are certain **maps**?

Comment: A *local coordinate* is usually a synonym for a *chart*. As I wrote in my answer, Miranda seems to have a slightly different (though equivalent) understanding of a local coordinate (or his wording is misleading). Anyway, since he gives rise to some confusion, I would say his terminology is not standard or at least imprecise.

Comment: In your question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4651308 you quote "Let $\psi$ be a chart of $X$ not in the atlas; our task is to define the holomorphic $1$-form with respect to $\psi$ or, equivalently, interms of the local coordinate $w$ of $\psi$. " This suggests to me that he wants to define he holomorphic $1$-form on the range $V$ of the cart $\psi$ where he can use a standard complex coordinate $w$. Once he has got this $1$-form, he can "shift" it via $\psi$ to a holomorphic $1$-form on the domain $U$ of the chart $\psi$.

Comment: "Then simply define the holomorphic $1$-form with respect to $\psi$ as $f(T(w))T'(w)dw$, where $z=T(w)$ describes the change of coordinates $\phi\circ \psi^{-1}$."  This clearly shows that $T$ is a function between open subsets of $\mathbb C$. Thus $T'(w)$ is the usual complex derivative of $T$ and $dw$ is just a symbol denoting the obvious $1$-form on $V$. Also see the definition of $1$-form on p. 106.

Comment: I see, thank you.